# How can I install g77 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 19.04, gcc, fortran

I just downloaded Ubuntu 19.04. I want to install a program that needs the g77 compiler to run. I followed the instructions explained in [Install G77 on Ubuntu >=14.04](http://seanelvidge.com/2017/01/install-g77-on-ubuntu-14-04/), but when typing the command

```
sudo apt install g77
```

an error appears:

```
E: Package 'g77' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is well past End of Life and not supported here any more.  YOu need to update to a supported Ubuntu release to get continued support.

Comment: https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/it-services/where-has-g77-gone-to

Comment: many thanks for your answer but I tried this command but doesn't work with me ... but when following the same instructions I used before but adding to them " [trusted=yes] " to the four lines of deb, the problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package g77 is not available in any currently supported version of Ubuntu, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. The fort77 utility is the interface to the Fortran compilation system. It will accept the full Fortran 77 language defined by the ANSI X3.9-1978 standard. fort77 can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install fort77
```

To test fort77 save this Hello world Fortran 77 code as hello-world.f:

```
      program hello_world
      implicit none
c
      character*32 text
c
      text = 'Hello World!'
      write (*,*) text
c
      end
```

To compile the code run the following command:

```
fort77 hello-world.f -o hello-world
```

This creates an executable file named hello-world. Run the program by typing `./hello-world` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Results:

```
Hello World!
```

---

GNU Fortran 95 compiler can also be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```

This is the GNU Fortran 95 compiler, which compiles Fortran 95 on platforms supported by the gcc compiler. It uses the gcc backend to generate optimized code. gfortran is backwards compatible with the same Hello world code example shown above, and the executable file that it generates will run. gfortran is not backwards compatible with all Fortran 77 code, so sometimes it's necessary to install fort77 for full Fortran 77 compatibility.

Comment: Many thanks for your help .... the problem is solved but another problem appeared when using 'make' command to install HYPODD program .... these lines appears : $ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory $
$ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory $ knowing that these files are existed in the following path "/usr/libx32/crti.o
/usr/mipsel-linux-gnu/lib/crti.o
/usr/lib32/crti.o
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o" how can I fix this problem?